# Reload the form without the form elements after submit

Tags: ajax, forms, drupal

I have a scenario which goes as described below.
I created a form using hook_form.
The action for submit button is ajax.
So my requirement is to load the form after submitting the submit button.

```
function demo_form_ajax_submit($form, $form_state) {
  // Dummy/dumb validation for demo purpose.
  $name = $form_state['input']['name'];
  $email = $form_state['input']['email'];
  $comment = $form_state['input']['comment'];
  $msg = $name . $email . $comment;

 // drupal_validate_form('demo_demo_form', $form, $form_state);
    if (form_get_errors()) {
        $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;
        return $form;

    }
   if (!empty($form_state['input']['name']) && !empty($form_state['input']  ['email']) && !empty($form_state['input']['comment'])) {
      mail("xxx@gmail.com","My subject",$msg);// Do it in live site
      return $form;
     }
  }
```

With my above code I am getting the form along with the form elements. Can you please help me with this.

Comment: Did you try not returning that $form variable you get as parameter...or just unset some fields from it?

Comment: You can find help from this page https://api.drupal.org/api/examples/ajax_example!ajax_example.module/group/ajax_example/7